# Find sum of Current month and Previous month values

Tags: oracle, hive, impala

I have a source table with employee account details for each month, date is String type (yyyyMMdd). Trying to find the sum of current month values and previous month values for each account.

```
Source data:

+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  date     | account     | division  |  amount  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB1       | 110      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB2       | 120      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB4       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB1       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB2       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190131  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

ran below query in impala but this is returning me same results for current as well as previous month.

```
select distinct * from (
SELECT 
sum(amount) over (partition BY account, a.date) AS asset_current,
sum(amount) over (partition BY account, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_timestamp(data_as_of_date,'yyyyMMdd'),-1))),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd')) AS asset_previous,
     account,
     date,
FROM employee_assets a
)x ;
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  date     | account     | current_month_sum  |  previous_month_sum  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190331  | 123         | 330                | 300                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190228  | 123         | 300                | 100                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190131  | 123         | 100                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

---

I have used the below query but it is returning asset_previous as month before if the previous month data is not available.

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    LAG(current_month_sum, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY adate) previous_month_sum  
FROM (
    SELECT adate, account, SUM(amount) current_month_sum  
    FROM employee_assets
    GROUP BY adate, account
) x
ORDER BY adate DESC
```

for example: We don't have input data for 20181231 for account 123, so asset_prev for month January should be 0, but query is returning 500 (which is amount for November'2018)
Input data:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  date     | account     | division  |  amount  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB1       | 110      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB2       | 120      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB4       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB1       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB2       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190131  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20181130  | 123         | ABX       | 500      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Query is returning:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  date     | account     | current_month_sum  |  previous_month_sum  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190331  | 123         | 330                | 300                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190228  | 123         | 300                | 100                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190131  | 123         | 100                | 500                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20191131  | 123         | 500                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  date     | account     | current_month_sum  |  previous_month_sum  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190331  | 123         | 330                | 300                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190228  | 123         | 300                | 100                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190131  | 123         | 100                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20191131  | 123         | 500                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What is the reason for `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_timestamp(data_as_of_date,'yyyyMMdd'),-1))),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd')`, why do you shuffle around with date and Unix timestamps? What is the data type of `data_as_of_date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation in an inner query, and use `LAG()` in the outer query to get the previous month's value in the `account` partition. The three-arguments form of `LAG()` lets you specify a default value.

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    LAG(current_month_sum, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY adate) previous_month_sum  
FROM (
    SELECT adate, account, SUM(amount) current_month_sum  
    FROM employee_assets
    GROUP BY adate, account
) x
ORDER BY adate DESC
```

Note: `date` is not a good choice for a column name, since it might clash with a reserved word. I renamed that column to `adate` in the query.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It returned correct result on actual data.

Comment: Welcome @ASaraf! Glad to help out.

Comment: Query works fine if we have account available in all months. I have one scenario where I don't have account "123" in 20190531 but it's there in 20190630 and 20190430.
So in month "20190630" its returning "20190430" April data in previous month value. In this case it should return "0" as in May account 123 is not present.
Please help in updating this query.

Comment: please help in updating this query.